# How to force download files using Laravel 5?

Tags: php, file, laravel, download, laravel-5

Yes I have read the documentation. :)

My controller method looks like:

```
public function download($id)
{
    $file = $this->fileRepo->find($id);

    $randomDir = md5(time() . $file->id . $file->user->id . str_random());

    mkdir(public_path() . '/files/' . $randomDir);

    $path = public_path() . '/files/' . $randomDir . '/' . $file->name;

    file_put_contents($path, base64_decode($file->data));

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');

    return response()->download($path);
}
```

It takes the BLOB from the database, converts it, saves it temporarily on the filesystem in the public folder under a random folder and then serves the download. The headers in postman show up like so:

```
Accept-Ranges → bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Headers → Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With, Application
Access-Control-Allow-Methods → POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin → *
Cache-Control → public
Connection → close
Content-Description → File Transfer
Content-Disposition → attachment; filename="taxonomy.odt"
Content-Length → 43626
Content-Type → application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text
Date → Wed, 18 Nov 2015 11:38:36 GMT
Host → localhost:8000
Last-Modified → Wed, 18 Nov 2015 11:38:36 GMT
X-Powered-By → PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14
```

I guess all the headers are set correct depending on what kind of file is being served (odt in this case).

I tried running this script to test the API for download:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $.ajax({
     url: "http://localhost:8000/api/files/53/download",
    method : "get",
     data : {
     },
     headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImNhcnBhcnRzIiwic3ViIjoiMSIsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo4MDAwXC9hcGlcL2F1dGhlbnRpY2F0ZSIsImlhdCI6IjE0NDc4MjQwOTEiLCJleHAiOiIxNDQ3ODc4MDkxIiwibmJmIjoiMTQ0NzgyNDA5MSIsImp0aSI6ImI2MzRiZDY4ZTMyNjA3OWE3OGYzNzlhNGVkYjJlYzRhIn0.oLF71WsOkl5kDdnRBkpKSbDHD_kCk45yONuB_TiIKxc'
     }
  })           
    .done(function (data) {
    // console.log(data);
  })
  .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
    alert("error: " + textStatus);
  });
</script>
```

I can uncomment the `.done` closure and it logs the file just fine. I have tried all sorts of files: json, text, odt and so on. JSON shows up just fine, so does text. The odt file has a lot of weird characters which is obvious why. But the browser just won't popup the download window. Why? What am I doing wrong?

PS: I also made sure that `fileinfo` extension is enabled. :)

Comment: Try return Response::download($filePath, 'Filename', ['content-type' => 'your_content_type']); and by the way since its a download header why would you use AJAX. You could simply access it via simple get request.

Comment: How will I send the token? Anyway I'll try your solution and tell you.

Comment: can you just redirect the browser to your download URL using `href.location = "http://localhost:8000/api/files/53/download"`?

Comment: No @msturdy I cannot do that. I cannot send the JWT with my GET request through the browser.

Comment: @Nouphal.M I tried the whole thing too. Still does not work. Moreover the name and the header are optional parameters. In fact if you look at the headers in the postman response, seems to have all of the required ones.

Comment: @Rohan  is it a typo base64_decode($file->data), u should be using encode i think..

Comment: No it is not a typo. http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php

Comment: No thats not what i meant. Is ur content base64 encoded earlier?

Comment: Yes @Nouphal.M You take a file, encode it in base64 to make it binary and then decode it to reverse it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No ajax request is needed. Just click on this link:

```
<a href="http://localhost:8000/api/files/53/download">Download</a>
```

The page will not reload by clicking this link. Just try it.

Comment: I cannot send the token using this approach. It won't work without a token.

Comment: Okay, surprisingly enough, the ajax was the problem. I could send the token via the URL too as the JWT package supports both headers and GET variables. So yes, just hitting the URL did it finally.

Answer (score 0):

If you need ajax then just do as follows when clicked download button:

```
var code = '<form target="iframeDownload" method="post" action="http://localhost:8000/api/files/53/download"><input type="hidden" name="token" value="your_token"></form>';
var $frm = $(code).attr('target', 'iframeDownload').appendTo('body').submit();
```

If you want to pass any variable just pass it through the form as hidden variables. You can also pass the token directly through the url itself. Just try it.

Answer (score 0):

In Blade Template

```
<a href="{!! route('admin.resource.download', array('file'=>$resource['file'])) !!}">{!! $resource['file'] !!}</a>
```

In routes.php

```
Route::get('resource/download',['as' => 'admin.resource.download','uses' => 'ResourceController@download']);
```

In Controller

```
public function download(Request $request){
        return response()->download(public_path('uploads/resource/'.$request['file']));  
    }
```

Works fine for me !!